# Laravel Reference a One-to-Many Table through a Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am having the most difficult time with this, and I'm not sure if the issue is the relationship or what. I have a 'users' table that has a many to many relationship (via a pivot table) with a 'practices' table. Practices, however, have a one-to-many relationship with a 'doctors' table, in which a practice can have many doctors, but a doctor can only belong to one practice. I also then have a many-to-many relationship between the doctors and a 'patients' table, which I would need to run counts and count-by-date sort of queries off of.

Currently, it is set to where a user can see what doctors they have by running a foreach loop on practices, and then on $practices->doctors. But this is not optimal, as the doctors then can't be sorted alphabetically and such. Can someone help me figure out how I can reference the doctor directly without needing the additional foreach loop?

This is my current code. Thanks in advance!

dashboard.blade.php

```
@foreach ($practices as $practice)
    @foreach ($practice->doctors as $doctor)
        Doctor Name:   {{$doctor->full_name}}
        Patient Count: {{$doctor->patients()->count()}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

DashboardController.php

```
$practices = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->practices();
return view('dashboard')->withPractices($practices);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no predefined eloquent relationship for your scenario. but we can create a relationship using another relationship.

I believe you have already created the relationship to 'practices' in the 'User Model' and 'doctors' in 'Practice Model'.

```
// in User Model
public function practices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Practices::class);
}

// in Practice Model
public funcion doctors()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Doctor::class);
}
```

You need a 'doctors' relationship in the 'User Model'.

```
// in User Model
public function doctors()
    $this->load(['practices.doctors' => function($query) use (&$relation) {
        $relation = $query;
    }]);

    return $relation;
}
```

now you can get 'doctors' for a 'user' like this.

```
$doctors = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->doctors;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a direct relationship by "skipping" the `practices` table:

```php
class User extends Model {
    public function doctors() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Doctor::class,
            'practice_user',
            null,
            'practice_id',
            null,
            'practice_id'
        );
    }
}
```